# Windows Form Application Query & Update Access Database

Tags: c#, database, windows, forms, datagridview

I'm new to C#. I'd like to query data from a access database from a Windows form. I've made a form with a DataGridView, and I've made a connection to database table. The GridView shows all the items present in the table. I'd like to do 2 things:

1. I've made couple of labels for fields, and I'd like to filter the data in GridView based on those fields of Table with a button click.
2. I'd like to have a EDIT button as well. If I edit a field in GridView Form, it'll update the field in database as well.

Assuming I have a table `Test` with Columns

- EmpName *(Text)*
- JoiningDate *(Date)*
- Assignment *(Yes/No)*
- Department *(Text)*

[image: Table Test]

Comment: Did you use DataAdapters/DataTable ? If yes the answer is easy. If no, you probably used a DataReader, and you need to make an update